Modify bookmarklet to recognize bold text
I'm trying to modify a great bookmarklet made by Rawbitz, to make it recognize bold, italic text or links and export correctly into workflowy, but asking ai chatbots gave me no solution.
I have to make the premise that I know nothing about programming.
The original code is the following:
javascript:(function C2W_2_9(){
    function eOPML(str){
        return str.replace(/&/g,'&amp;amp;').replace(/</g,'&amp;lt;').replace(/>/g,'&amp;gt;').replace(/"/g,'&quot;').replace(/(\n)/g,'&#10;')
    }
        
    function%20copyThat(str){
        const%20t=document.createElement("textarea");
        t.value=str;
        document.body.appendChild(t);
        t.select();
        const%20success=document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(t);
        return%20success}
    
    function%20toastMsg(str,sec,err){
        WF.showMessage(str,err);
        setTimeout(WF.hideMessage,(sec||2)*1e3)
    }
    
    const%20IS_WF=typeof%20WF==="object"&&typeof%20WF.currentItem==="function";
    
    const%20copyAndToastExt=(str,message,isWF)=>copyThat(str)?isWF?toastMsg(message,2):null:prompt("\nCopy%20failed.\n\nCopy%20this%20manually.",str);
    
    const%20name=eOPML(document.title.replace(/%20-%20WorkFlowy$/,""));
    const%20bullet=IS_WF?`&lt;i&gt;See:%20&quot;${name}&quot;&lt;/i&gt;`:name;
    const%20selection=window.getSelection().toString();
    const%20link=eOPML(location.href);
    const%20note=selection?`..${link}&#10;&#10;
    
${eOPML(selection)}`:link;
    const%20clip=`<opml><body><outline%20text="${bullet}"%20_note="${note}"%20/></body></opml>`;
    copyAndToastExt(clip,"Clip%20copied!",IS_WF)
})(); 

Thanks!
already tried with chatgpt but no results
